# Create array from Ajax POST Request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using this code to create an array using an Ajax Post request.

```
$('#accountholderEmail').on('keyup',function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/section/get_data?getCustomer=1", 
            cache: false, 
            success: function(data){
                var email_array = data;
            }
        });
        console.log(email_array);
});
```

`data` from the Ajax request is returning an array but its telling me that email_array is not defined in the `console.log(email_array);`

How can i get this variable populated with the returned data from the ajax request

Comment: Put the `console.log()` inside the `success` function, where the value actually is.

Comment: email_array would have data. Its an asynchronous call and so before your POST request is completed, console logs email_array. (before you get response from your post request, email_array doesnt have any value.)
Check by printing your email_array in success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize email_array in function success so want console.log it you have to push it into funciton success

```
$('#accountholderEmail').on('keyup',function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/section/get_data?getCustomer=1", 
            cache: false, 
            success: function(data){
                var email_array = data;
                console.log(email_array);
            }
        });

});
```